# Using a namespace in place of a static class in C++?

Tags: c++

Is it good or okay practice to use a namespace as a static class? For example:

```
namespace MyStaticFunctions {
    void doSomething();
}
```

Versus:

```
class MyStaticFunctions {
    static void doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I prefer "extern" because only C++ can do such thing in OOP ;) Also for C or Objective C compatibility.

Comment: *"Is it good or okay practice to use a namespace as a static class"* - In fact it is by far much better practice than your second option. The latter is only preferred (or rather needed) if you need a *"template namespace"* or want to make a whole namespace a friend of another class (though that might be questionable, too).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "static class" in C++, so from a C++ point of view you're not using it "as a static class", you're using it "as a namespace". It's certainly accepted practice to use namespaces to group functions together.

It's up to you, though, how big you want the groups to be. It's not unusual for C++ libraries to use a single namespace for the whole public interface. That might come as a surprise to someone who is used to (say) Java, where classes are often used to group together smaller numbers of static methods. Since C++ was here first, you could say that Java is using classes as namespaces.

So, in C++ you don't tend to see classes similar to `java.util.Collections` or `java.lang.Math`, full of static members. If you want groups of functions like that in C++, use namespaces.

The exception (isn't there always a special case in C++?) is traits types like `std::numeric_limits<T>`, where the template parameter makes the class do something that a namespace can't do. You could define a namespace `numeric_limits` containing function templates `max<T>()`, `min<T>()` etc, but it's not as good. Firstly, it groups things slightly differently, the type `T` appears "lower down the hierarchy". Secondly it doesn't do everything that a traits type does, because there's no such thing as an "object template" that would let you define a value `numeric_limits::digits<T>`.

I don't know C# well enough to comment on the practical uses of static classes there, but AFAIK it's just a class restricted to having no non-static members, so it's analogous to those Java classes.

Comment: +1 Another case where a *"static class"* might come in handy would be if you want to make an entire namespace a friend of another class (though that design might be questionable in the first place, but can ease a lot sometimes).

Comment: Another case where _namespaces_ are better. you can use `using namespace MyStaticFunctions` if you are going to use more of this funtctions in a function

Answer (score 24):

In C++, you are actually encouraged at the language level to use a `namespace` rather than a `class` containing only `static` methods because of Koenig's lookup (aka Argument Dependent Lookup).

Example:

```
namespace geometry {
    struct Point { int x, y; };

    double distance_from_center(Point const& p) {
        return sqrt(p.x * p.x + p.y + p.y);
    }
} // namespace geometry

int main() {
    geometry::Point const p{3, 4}; // must qualify

    std::cout << distance_from_center(p) << "\n"; // not qualified
}
```

If `distance_from_center` is written as a `static` method in a `class`, then you need to explicitly qualify it each time.

Comment: I never knew this! however being explicit would make it more readable

Comment: @balki: more readable or more cluttered ? It's always a fine balance. It might be a bit dazzling for Java/C# guys, but it's idiomatic in C++ so there is no issue. Furthermore, in generic code (templates), it's much easier.

Comment: What does "explicitly qualify" mean?

Comment: @C.Binair: If you have `struct Geometry { static double distance(Point const&); }`, then you need to call it with `Geometry::distance(point)` (outside of the `Geometry` methods). The "qualification" I refer to is the `Geometry::` part, which is explicit. On the other hand, with a namespace as above, `distance(point)` will work if the function is defined in the same namespace as the class, regardless of where the call is. No qualification needed.

Answer (score 8):

It's a tough and interesting question for me personally, so decided to share my humble opinion

Considering the difference between "static" class (only static members) and namespace:

1. a namespace can be scattered over multiple files: additional flexibility but should be used carefully.
2. a namespace provides argument dependent lookup ([see Matthieu M. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14361756/453271)): useful in specific situations
3. a "static" class can have access modifiers and can form an hierarchy: I think private members declared in class interface and visible to its clients is a C++ feature that was dictated more by technical, not logical reasons. I don't see any benefits of private static members. Protected members for "static" hierarchy? Never seen any.
4. a "static" class can be a "template", in addition to template members: see [Steve Jessop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14361552/453271) for a great example from STL

From maintenance point of view, sometimes you decide to make a class "static" (like a singleton), but then requirement changed and you need multiple instances. "Static" class would be easier to transform than namespace.

And, finally, to answer your question:

if you don't need special features of "static" class or namespace, use what you like more :)

Comment: Now I desperately want to think of a use for a protected member in a class having only static members. Maybe some kind of CRTP-like situation, where a class naturally has a special relationship with its derived classes?

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

Is the method logically related to a class? If so, make it a member, otherwise place it in a namespace.

Functionally, they're the same, but there's more to code than function, right? For example, consider a method that returns the name of the class:

```
struct MyClass
{
    static std::string getName() { return "MyClass"; }
}
```

You could obviously place the method outside, in a `namespace`, and get the same result, but it logically belongs to the class.

Comment: What does it mean "logically related to a class"?

Comment: @AndyT: well, its logic is strongly related to that of the class.

Comment: Scott Meyers has different logic stated in this [article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)