# Prevent instantiation of C++11 class by "deleting" copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I wanted to create a "static class" in C++11, i.e. a class with only static methods and no possibility to instantiate or inherit.
Came up with the following solution:

```
class Foo final {
  public:
    static void methodA(...);
    static int methodB(...);
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
};
```

This way the compiler creates neither a default nor a copy constructor. Visual Studio's IntelliSense also confirms this as it does not provide **any** constructor auto-complete when typing `Foo(`.

I'm wondering if this solution is in any way preferable to the "common" approach of making the default constructor private. Are there any pros/cons?

Comment: Why not use a namespace instead?

Comment: Yeah, if you're not ever using the class features, you're not creating a class. You're creating a namespace.

Comment: Making the constructor private is all we could do without the delete keyword.  The effect is the same, and no code is generated.  I'd go with the new syntax, if only because it is more readable.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as "static class" in C++, namespace is the preferred option to group static functions, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14361552/4669663

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference to making the ctor private is that this was used for older C++ standards that didn't allow you to use `= delete`. The older form of doing this is not as "clean," as it relies on the linker to give an error message, not the compiler. If your ctor is private and without a definition, but you call it anyway (from within a class function, for example,) the linker would be responsible for aborting the build process with an error (since the ctor is only declared, not defined.) The `= delete` form is cleaner since the compiler can now issue an error directly.

However, what you're after here is very similar to a namespace. So I'd suggest you do this instead:

```
namespace Foo {
    void methodA(...);
    int methodB(...);
}
```

This doesn't change the fully qualified form for calling the functions. Like before, you call `methodA()` with `Foo::methodA()`, so this should act as a drop-in replacement.

You also gain the ability to drop the `Foo::` with a `using` statement if you want. For example:

```
using Foo::methodA;
methodA(); // Valid call.
```

Or just `using Foo;` to bring all identifiers from `Foo` into the current scope without having to prefix any of them with `Foo::`. (Usual caveat applies here about namespace pollution.)

You can't do this with static class functions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using the wrong tool for the job, a `namespace` (as per @jamesdlin's comment) will do what you want:

```
namespace Foo {
    void methodA(...);
    int methodB(...);
};
```